# 'System.Web.HttpException' Additional information: Unable to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-config, httpexception

LTL; FTP here.

I'm doing an eCommerce site following Shakeel Osmani's Tutorial [here](https://shakeelosmani.wordpress.com/2015/12/27/asp-net-mvc-step-by-step-complete-e-commerce-tutorial/).

The issue arises when I try to register a new user in the website, it throws an "'System.Web.HttpException' Additional information: Unable to connect to SQL Server database." exception, and I can't find the problem anywhere.

I'm using VS2015 codefirst approach, and the code for the AccountsController is the following:

```html
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using eProject.Models;

namespace eProject.Controllers
{
    public class AccountsController : Controller
    {

        private void MigrateShoppingCart(string userName)
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            cart.MigrateCart(userName);
            Session[ShoppingCart.CartSessionKey] = userName;
        }

        public ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    MigrateShoppingCart(model.UserName);

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
            cart.EmptyCart();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, "question", "answer", true, null, out createStatus);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    MigrateShoppingCart(model.UserName);

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
                // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                try
                {
                    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
                    changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                }

                if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult ChangePasswordSuccess()
        {
            return View();
        }

        #region Status Codes
        private static string ErrorCodeToString(MembershipCreateStatus createStatus)
        {
            // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177550 for
            // a full list of status codes.
            switch (createStatus)
            {
                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                    return "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                    return "A user name for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                    return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                    return "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                    return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
                    return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
                    return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
                    return "The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
                    return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                default:
                    return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

My Web.config is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I have to deliver this very soon (Class project) and I have followed pretty much every answer I could find about this in this and other forums, like adding a

```html
<remove name="RoleManager" />
```

tag in web.config, funny thing is that when I add the connection string:

```html
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MvcAffableBean" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MvcAffableBean;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

the webapp doesn't start at all.

Please help!

The complete exception is:

```html
System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
  Source=System.Web
  WebEventCode=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
       at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureDBFile(String connectionString)
       at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)
       at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
       at System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
       at eProject.Controllers.AccountsController.Register(RegisterModel model) in c:\users\hermes lizama\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\eProject\eProject\Controllers\AccountsController.cs:line 75
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException: 
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
       Source=System.Web
       WebEventCode=0
       StackTrace:
            at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString)
            at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install)
            at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString)
            at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
       InnerException: 
            Class=20
            ErrorCode=-2146232060
            HResult=-2146232060
            LineNumber=0
            Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
            Number=-1
            Server=""
            Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
            State=0
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
                 at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString)
            InnerException:
```

Comment: What do you mean "the webapp doesn't start at all" when adding DB connection string? Obviously your app requires connection string to interact with DB instances, the error clearly said that your app doesn't have connection to DB.

Comment: That is exactly the issue. When i go to my web.config and add the connection string, the webapp throws `An exception of type 'System.Data.DataException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.`

Which turns into a very annoying error since it doesn't show where it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on same sample project and I had same issue you have.

I fixed it by adding config and connection string

```
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
      name="SqlMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="SqlConn"
      applicationName="MembershipAndRoleProviderSample"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="false"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="true"
      passwordFormat="Hashed" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and

```
  <add name="SqlConn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True;" />
```